# RabbitMQ memory leak?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq

I am using a single instance of RabbitMQ on a kubernetes cluster. The RabbitMQ pod has access to 15Go of RAM and is setup with a high watermark of 10Go.

After a few hours of usage (and a few queues storing 60 Millions persistent messages) the UI of RabbitMQ show a usage of 4GB (out of the 10GB high watermark) but the rabbitMQ pod is using almost 12GB of RAM.

Nothing else than RabbitMQ is running on this pod.
Running a `ps` command on the pod show that the command `/usr/lib/erlang/erts-8.3/bin/beam.smp -W w -A 64 -P 1048576 -t 5000000 -st` is using almost 10GB of memory :

```
root@rabbitmq-0:/# ps -aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
rabbitmq     1  0.0  0.0   4340   152 ?        Ss   Apr25   0:00 /bin/sh -e /usr
rabbitmq   131  0.0  0.0  11492   116 ?        S    Apr25   0:00 /usr/lib/erlang
rabbitmq   266  256 66.7 15384208 10272940 ?   Sl   Apr25 3596:13 /usr/lib/erlan
rabbitmq   364  0.0  0.0   4220   400 ?        Ss   Apr25   0:01 erl_child_setup
rabbitmq   376  0.0  0.0  11456   108 ?        Ss   Apr25   0:00 inet_gethost 4
rabbitmq   377  0.0  0.0  13552  1140 ?        S    Apr25   0:00 inet_gethost 4
root       406  0.0  0.0  20292  2508 ?        Ss+  Apr25   0:00 bash
root     17817  0.0  0.0  20296  3280 ?        Ss   14:35   0:00 bash
root     18322  0.0  0.0  17504  2068 ?        R+   15:05   0:00 ps -aux
```

**Is this difference between 4GB and 10GB normal or a memory leak?**

`rabbitmqctl report` command result :

```
{memory,
     [{total,4165388576},
      {connection_readers,677672},
      {connection_writers,282352},
      {connection_channels,1721776},
      {connection_other,2916512},
      {queue_procs,2559842512},
      {queue_slave_procs,0},
      {plugins,7852776},
      {other_proc,33485720},
      {mnesia,120680},
      {metrics,12540648},
      {mgmt_db,5339864},
      {msg_index,142928},
      {other_ets,19053856},
      {binary,1476618400},
      {code,24747054},
      {atom,1033401},
      {other_system,31550241}]},
```

**RabbitMQ 3.6.9, Erlang 19.3**

Comment: Which versions of rabbitmq and erlang?

Comment: @MartinSchröder RabbitMQ 3.6.9, Erlang 19.3 . Thanks

Comment: what does `free -m` say?

Comment: make sure you're using lazy queues https://www.rabbitmq.com/lazy-queues.html